# Show dateTime column from MySql Database to GridView in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having problems with displaying a column from mysql database to a gridView. The column is DateTime in sql format is a such "2016-03-09 05:09:00". The problem i am facing is that other column gets displayed to the gridView but not the dateTime from Mysql database.

Here is the code for getting the columns from the database:

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT app_number, app_datetime, app_confirm, pat_ID, rec_ID, doc_ID FROM appointment"))

            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the gridView :

```
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
```

```
  <asp:BoundField DataField="app_number" HeaderText="App#" ReadOnly="true" />

  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="App Date">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("app_datetime")%>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtApp_datetime" Text='<%# Eval("app_datetime")%>' />
      </EditItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>

  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <%# Eval("app_confirm")%>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtConfirm" Text='<%# Eval("app_confirm")%>' />
      </EditItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>


  <asp:BoundField DataField="pat_ID" HeaderText="Patient ID" ReadOnly="true" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="rec_ID" HeaderText="Receptionist" ReadOnly="true" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="doc_ID" HeaderText="Doctor" ReadOnly="true" />



</Columns>


  <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
  <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
  <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
  <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />
```

The output i Get
[image: Data that is Displayed in gridView]

Comment: MySQL has [appropriate data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) for storing date/time. Why don't you use those? Then in .NET you can a `DateTime` object that you can display however you want.

Comment: Have you checked the backend, app_datetime have value or not?

Comment: The problem is that its stored correct format but i cannot display using gridview @mason

Comment: The value is in backend @Vicky_Thinking

Comment: It looks like `app_datetime` is Null or Empty, as @Vicky_Thinking also mentioned. Or you are hiding or removing the cell contents in a RowDataBound event.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this Instead of your Text hope this works,

```
Text='<%# Eval("app_datetime", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ItemTemplate>
    <%# string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Eval("app_datetime"))%>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Makes no difference @Prasanna Kumar J